# How do I add a provided jar to my Run Configuration

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My maven pom defines a dependency on foo.jar with scope:provided.

Demo.java is located under src/main/java.  It imports classes provided by foo.  If I create a run configuration for this class, running the class throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

TestDemo.java is located under src/main/test.  It is nothing but a wrapper around Demo.  If I create a run configuration for this class, everything just works.

If I update that working configuration, changing the main class to Demo, I see the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError again.

Is there a better way to run my main classes within the IDE than hacking wrappers into src/main/test ?

Comment: Is the import on an implementation, or on an interface?

Answer (score 0):

A `provided` scope dependency must be on the classpath at runtime, but isn't required for compilation. If you require the dependency for compilation, which it sounds like you do, then you must not have a `provided` scope.

Typically, libraries that are `provided` have `compile` scoped interface libraries that are used for compilation, and only the implementation is provided at runtime.